# Form not submitting html php

Tags: php, forms

My form is not submitting, My database insert class works and I have tested. But my form seems not to want to submit or post values from my form. Is there something I left out?

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="sub_newsletter.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Newsletter</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name : </td>
<td><input name="name" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email : </td>
<td><input name="email" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" name="check_spam" id="check_spam" size="30" style="display:none;" />  </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="image" name="submit" src="images/sub.jpg" style="width:180px; height:70px;"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

My submit script

```
<?php
include('includes/database.php');
include('includes/settings.php');
include('includes/newsletter.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
//to check if posting
echo $username=rtrim($_POST['name']);
echo $myemail=rtrim($_POST['email']);
//
$check=$_POST['check_spam'];
if(!empty($check)){ echo "You are spam"; } else{
$username=rtrim($_POST['name']);
$myemail=rtrim($_POST['email']);
$news =  new Newsletter();
$new->first_name=$username;
$new->email=$myemail;
$new->create();
echo "<script>alert(\"Thank you for your subscription\"); </script>";
echo "<script>window.location.replace(\"index.html\"); </script>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: where is <input type="submit">?

Comment: It's because you're using and image button - `<input type="image"/>` replace it with a submit button - `<input type="submit" name="submit">` and simply apply CSS to enhance its look. An image button passes X and Y coordinates when you click it and such conditions as you mentioned - `if (isset($_POST['submit'])){}` will never be satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously missed submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Since you have already a field with that name, just change it or use a different name.

Comment: Don't forget to give a name attribute. It will not be accessed on the server otherwise.